# Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Touch has a locked boot-loader

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bootloader

I asked the Meizu support responsible for the Ubuntu Touch, about shipping, taxes and if the bootloader was locked.

The information I received is surprising to me. Can someone else confirm this, pretty please?

Will the bootloader really be fully locked? Is that even possible, or won't such a thing prevent us from enjoying Ubuntu-Touch?

> Hello Christoph,
>
> Thanks for your interest and support.
>
> After your purchase through the en.JD.com, DHL express would help us
>   to send the phone to you, and the shipping is free. So only if your
>   destination is covered by the DHL network, you can get it
>   successfully. As for the local taxes, it depends on the local customs
>   requirements, I cannot answer you specifically for now. The
>   boot-loader is locked.  If your phone run into any problem, you can
>   contact with the after-sales team of en.JD.com. We've authorized them
>   to help with the after-sales services.
>
> May the information above be helpful for you. Feel free to contact us
>   if you have any other questions.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Your friends at Meizu

Answer (score 1):

works like a charm, no more locked bootloader on PRO5.
Here is how to do it, I can confirm it's possible and without much of a trouble.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/how-to/tutorial-unlock-bootloader-meizu-pro-5-t3303127

Comment: Link-only answers are not preferred here (the link could die in a few months). Please provide a more complete answer.

Comment: I would provide a more info but that would be just copy and paste as it's all been done and I don't deserve any credit for that, I just wanted to point to a right direction and way to do it.

Comment: That is not an issue, as long as you refer to the post as the source. Alternatively, if you don't bother to write a proper answer, then a comment is the best option.

Comment: Just to confirm that the answer above from stef01 and linking to: http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/how-to/tutorial-unlock-bootloader-meizu-pro-5-t3303127 is the correct and helpful answer, containing all the details on how to proceed. Neither he nor I can give a more detailed answer because the above link has written in bold at the top: **Please do not create mirrors of the firmware or replicate this method on other websites. If you want to share this method with people on other websites, please just re-direct them to this page.**

Answer (score 0):

All ARM devices are locked and all chip makers retain control over parts of the lock process they do not give to OEMs. This does not prevent you from installing a custom OS, necessarily, but it prevents you from being certain your device was, is, or can be secure.

The secureboot crisis already happened. Sorry, it doesn't seem like there's much you can do about it unless you want to go put a gun to somebody's head.